# Apache breaks laravel routes when virtualhost points outside HTDOCS

Tags: php, laravel, apache, api, virtualhost

i'm trying to move my Laravel 5.5 project to Apache. 
The problem is that when i create a virtual host that points to outside the htdocs folder, it simply breaks all my API routes when calling something other than the root ('/').

Those are my setup files:

Hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   project-inside.dev
127.0.0.1   project-outside.dev
```

httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName project-inside.dev
  DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\api_project\public"
  <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\api_project\public">
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName project-outside.dev
  DocumentRoot "C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\projects\api_project\public"
  <Directory "C:\Users\%userprofile%\Desktop\projects\api_project\public">
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If i send a postman request to *project-inside.dev* (Project files are inside htdocs), every single route works great. In the other hand, if i try to send a postman request to *project-outside.dev* (Project files are sitting at my desktop), only the home route works, requests sent to routes like *project-outside.dev/api/login* returns an 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried running this outside htdocs

```
composer dump-autoload
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache
```